# Are we a forum that deals with questions about capitalism and monopolies?

Tags: discussion

I need to say to start with that I was raised left-wing. My dad is a socialist, but I believe in capitalism. I think that we should all strive to create the best product and make sure our company works for all of us by doing so. I think that's important.

But if this meta-community is worth anything, and I'm certain it is, I would like to see it be able to deal with questions not about just individual employees but about what we want a company entity to be and what it should be tasked with achieving.

I don't see this come up often and I don't want to be seen as opposing anyone who thinks it shouldn't be discussable or being distruptive or anything, I just hope asking the question will make for a useful discussion.

Comment: "*I just hope asking the question...*" What question exactly are you asking though? For starters: this is not a forum. We are a Q&A site. I'm not sure "crony capitalism" comes into it anywhere nor should there ever be a need to specify your political leanings...

Comment: "I think that we should all strive to create the best product and make sure our company works for all of us by doing so." This is not practical capitalism

Comment: @Kilisi I disagree. I think the best should rise to the top

Comment: @What'sinaGoogleSearch it makes no difference what you think, fairytales aren't real life

Answer (score 11):

> Are we a forum that deals with questions about crony capitalism and
>   monopolies?

No.

Comment: Illuminating answer there. Why don't you want it discussed?

Comment: My personal belief is that the best product for the consumer should be the product that gets to market. I think the stagnation of much of the tech industry has been because that principal has been forgotten.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter - of course I never said that I don't want it discussed. I wrote  that we aren't a forum that deals with the relative merits of socialism versus capitalism. You could probably discuss it in Chat if you can find someone else interested.

Comment: You don't want to discuss that because it might implicate you. SE in general makes sure there are rules that ensure only the things it wants discussed are discussed and the 'we're not a forum' idea only cuts to when certain things are unseemly, or the status quo don't like that idea they might be at issue.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter - LOL! Have fun. I don't make the forum rules here.

Comment: I'm building, with a small team, something to replace SE. We already have some industry backers.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter - terrific! Let us know when it's done, where to find it, and what your rules are.

Comment: Currently we're looking at early release within 2020, final quarter.

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter - great. Let me know if you want a Beta Tester. I've done a fair bit of that over my career.

Comment: That's a nice offer, thanks :) I might just take you up on it

Comment: @PeterDavidCarter - please do. I was a QA professional for over 25 years. I enjoy testing.